# Check multiple Checkbox jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this code to get back a json string:

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/editTask.php?ID="+tid,function(result){
        $.each(result.staff, function() { 
            $("#checkbox[value=" + this + "]").prop('checked');
        });
});
```

The json looks like this

```
{"staff":[13,17,15]}
```

I have a PHP snippet like this

```
<div id="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($user_list); ++$i) {
  echo '<label>'
      .'<input type="checkbox" name="tasksUser[]" 
           value="'.$user_list[$i]['uid'].'">'
      .$user_list[$i]['surname'].', '.$user_list[$i]['forename']
      .'</label><br />';
}
?>
</div>
```

I want that every checkbox that has the value that is in **result.staff** be checked. But I think I have an error in my each part. But in the Firefox console is no error showing.

Could you help me?

Comment: what actually is your error then? does it not work, does it check some of them?

Comment: No item is checked. Bute I know that they matched.

Comment: Yea because you have few issue in your code. You are trying to use id but there is no id.

Comment: formatted to more readable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an issue in your $.each function.

```
 $.each(result.staff, 
     function() { 
         $("#checkbox[value=" + this + "]").prop('checked');
            ^
            Here is the issue.
     });
 });
```

As you don't have any id or class associated with element you can access it using element name/+type

You must replace your code with

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][value=" + this + "]").prop("checked", true);
```

Here I am accessing all checkboxes with values  available and setting checked as true.

Answer (score 0):

You're using this selector to look for checkboxes:

`$("#checkbox[value...]")`

However, the `#` symbol in a selector looks for an element with that `ID`.

The checkboxes in your PHP loop do not have a specified ID or class, so you could select them with:

`#(":checkbox[value...]")`